# Data do not display when ajax request success

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, leaflet

In Laravel, I have this controller:

```php
public function getData()
{
    $data = Bencana::all()->pluck('coord');
    return response($data);
}
```

That's code for loading data from my database and my JS looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : '{{ route('getdata') }}',
    headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(response) {
        // console.log(response);
        var layer = L.geoJson(response, {
            style : myStyle
        }).addTo(map);
    }
});
```

that request is not showing the Circle, Point, Polygon data on my map. I'm stuck here.

Can anyone tell me what should I do next?

EDIT: There is no error in Console, but there is different output from my database.

```sql
{ type : manythings, another :{}}
```

I save the coordinate with json type to my table. When I try to return into map, console displays:

```
{\type : \"somelikethat", \another :\"{}}
```

Comment: Could you try `response.data`?

Comment: @Rolf OP is using jQuery, not axios.

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` display?

Comment: Aaah okay! Haven't used jQuery for a while ;)

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Are you positive that `L` and `map` are already set properly when that code runs?

Comment: It could help to use `return response()->json($data);` btw

Comment: My console green, nothing error

Comment: Idk why, when i try return to console. My json data become {\"type":"...",\blehblehbleh

Comment: Is that normal have symbol \ on return??

Comment: can you just `dd()` something and see whats in output . You may calling for a wrong route. Not sure but better if you could check. Also check your network activities. It will show you the exact error

Comment: did you test response()->json([$data]) ?

Comment: What field type of your using for `coord`? Please can you also show an example piece of data that is stored in this field in the database?

Comment: Field type i used for coord is long text type, i have many coordinate from polygon draw

Answer (score 0):

if you set `dataType: 'json'` in ajax, you must in controller use `return response()->json($data);`

if you want set a key for data, you can try this : `return response()->json(['data' => $data]);`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I would probably suggest returning `JsonResponse` from the controller, although, if you're returning array, it should already be converted to json.
So the first thing I would change would be controller response:

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

public function getData()
{
    $data = Bencana::all()->pluck('coord');

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

Next thing to check is what you actually need to pass to the `geoJson` method. Just to be clear - are you using [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/)?

If so, on the landing page there is an example of the json structure that you need to pass in - although I'm sure you already know that. Just compare the response you are sending from your controller to the recommended structure - perhaps there's some issue there.

By looking at their example you need `type` and `geometry` property of the json object.

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "Dinagat Islands"
    }
}
```

Sorry if these things sound obvious, but sometimes double checking helps.